# How to make menu block item show up?

Tags: 7, theming, blocks, navigation

I have a menu block composed of menu items with submenu items. 
Each menu item is displayed separately in a block.

They are all set to appear on every page, no restrictions. However if I were to access one of the submenu items, the entire menu item (including the submenu items) belonging to it does no longer appear.

I have checked in variables from `template_preprocess_page`, the region where the menu item block should appear is showing as empty.

How can I make it show up?

Comment: Are you using drupal default theme ?

Comment: no, i am using a custom theme

Comment: Using bootstarap

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue, "Make the starting level follow the active menu item." needs to be unticked.

Comment: Thank you for following up to your own question. I think that it works as an answer for you, but it may be helpful to others later to expand upon the why and how bit.